# Yourls gets only the first Word for Title

Tags: php, yourls

My Code is working fine but somehow Yourls is getting only the first Word of the Site Title. It does not forward anything after the space of the first Word.

The Code

```
$Artikel    =   $smarty->get_template_vars('Artikel');
$keyword    =   $Artikel->cArtNr;
$title      =   $Artikel->cName;
$short = file_get_contents(''.$siteurl.'/yourls-api.php?signature='.$signature.'&action=shorturl&url='.$shorturl.'&format='.$format.'&keyword='.$keyword.'&title='.$title.'');
```

If the Title is **"My first Computer"** than only **"My"** is set as Title. Is it cause my Code or Yourls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely related to URL character encoding. You are not encoding the space in `$title`, rendering the URI invalid.

You can use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to perform this on your query string arguments, but it may be easier and better to refactor your code to use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$query = http_build_query(array(
    'signature' => $signature,
    'action' => 'shorturl',
    'url' = $shorturl,
    'format' => $format,
    'keyword' => $keyword,
    'title' => $title
));
file_get_contents($siteurl . '/yourls-api.php?' . $query);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jacob! Well I had problem with all arrays all together.. As I left only the title inside than it worked.. Dont know why not all of them work together but you helped me a lot!